# AspNetIdentityDocumentDB and Cross partition query is required but disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

I have an app that uses CosmosDb as the database and using AspNetIdentityDocument. When I call var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false), i get the error Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey

void InitializeDocumentClient(DocumentClient client) code attempts to create the container if not there. It works for the creating the container on my CossmosDb emultated store but fails on the Azure store requiring a partition key! My app works on the emulated store!

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultDocumentClientForIdentity(
            builder.Configuration.GetValue<Uri>("DocumentDbClient:EndpointUri"),
            builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DocumentDbClient:AuthorizationKey"),
            afterCreation: InitializeDocumentClient);

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, DocumentDbIdentityRole>()
.AddDocumentDbStores(options =>
{
    options.UserStoreDocumentCollection = "AspNetIdentity";
    options.Database = "RNPbooking";
})
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();




void InitializeDocumentClient(DocumentClient client)
```

{
try
{
var db = client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("RNPbooking")).Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
ae.Handle(ex =>
{
if (ex.GetType() == typeof(DocumentClientException) && ((DocumentClientException)ex).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
var db = client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Database() { Id = "RNPbooking" }).Result;
return true;
}

```
        return false;
    });
}

try
{
    var collection = client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("RNPbooking", "AspNetIdentity")).Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Handle(ex =>
    {
        if (ex.GetType() == typeof(DocumentClientException) && ((DocumentClientException)ex).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection()
            {
                Id = "AspNetIdentity"
            };
            
            collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("RNPbooking"),collection).Result;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
```

}
}

Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin)]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    
    public CosmosClient _client;

    public AdminController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,

        )
    
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill in  CreateDocumentCollectionUri method with FeedOptions object as a parameter

```
 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery=true})
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: From the code examples, you seem to be using this library https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb, `AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb`.

This error means the library you are using is performing a Document Query in their code at some point, it is not related to the creation of the Database or Collection.

The library code must be using `CreateDocumentQuery` somewhere, that code is missing:

```
 new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
```

If you search their code base, you will see multiple scenarios like that: https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/search?q=CreateDocumentQuery

Because this code is out of your control, you should try and contact the owner to see if this is a fix they can do on their end. The code for the library doesn't seem to have been updated in several years, so maybe this library is not maintained?

Comment: My code does not call createDocumentQuery. I call the UserManager from AspNeteCore.Identity so not sure where to go with this

Comment: Do you use any Nuget package to use Cosmos DB for your identity management? Which is it? THe problem might lay in that package.

Comment: Sharing the full stack trace of the exception you are getting should point you to the code that has the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using this library? https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb `AddDefaultDocumentClientForIdentity` seems to be an extension coming from there

Comment: Yes I’m using codekoeing/AspNetCore.Identity.Document

Comment: See the updated answer. You will need to reach the author of that library to fix the issue or clone the code yourself and maintain your own fork of the code with the fixed statements.

Comment: Not sure how I would clone the code but thank you

Comment: Clone = Download locally a copy of the repository and do project reference to it.